# How to insert ID from user table to other table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hi I have the user table and the ID is auto incremented, now I collect some information about the same users in a different page and insert into a new table, so I want to insert the ID from user table to a new table.

Here is my userID that I want to insert into new table.

```
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $pid=$row["userID"];
```

I am using AJAX to send the values into the different page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function post(){
      var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
      var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

      if(firstname && lastname && email && phone)
       {
       $.ajax
      ({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'secondpage.php',
      data: 
      {
      firstname:firstname,
      lastname:lastname,
      email:email,
      phone:phone
      },
     success: function (response) 
     {
     document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Profile updated successfully";

        }
      });
    }

    return false;
  }
 </script>
```

Below is the secondpage.php

```
     <?php
     session_start();
     require_once 'class.user.php';
     $host="localhost";
     $username="root";
     $password="";
     $databasename="mydb";

     $connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
     $db=mysql_select_db($databasename);
     echo "connected";


    if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && 
    isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']))
    {
      $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
      $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
      $email=$_POST['email'];
      $phone=$_POST['phone'];


      $insert=mysql_query("insert into tbl_profile 
      (firstname,lastname,email, phone) values('$firstname', 
      '$lastname','$email','$phone')"); 
       $id=mysql_insert_id($insert); 


       }

      ?>
```

Now how do I insert  $pid=$row["userID"] value into tbl_profile. I have a column user_id in tbl_profile. Any help is deeply appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You should consider posting user id along with other information in ajax. In second page apply validation to check if user id is of the same user who is submitting information OR if its admin user then you might not need to validate.

Comment: You're fetching the user ID on your first page? (Which has the ajax)

Comment: @Akshay Yes I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type='hidden' name='pid' id='pid' value="<?php echo $pid; ?>">
```

**Ajax**
....
**

```
data: 
      {
      firstname:firstname,
      lastname:lastname,
      email:email,
      phone:phone,
      pid = $("#pid").val()
      },
```

**

**PHP**

```
$pid = $_POST['pid']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to store your $pid value to an hidden input then get the value of hidden input to your javascript

Comment: I used the similar approach, it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't use mysql_query because it's removed in PHP 7.x
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Second,

```
$insert=mysql_query("insert into tbl_profile 
  (firstname,lastname,email, phone, user_id) values('$firstname', 
  '$lastname','$email','$phone', $_SESSION['userSession'])");
```

Third, this is susceptible for injections. You should NEVER store raw data from POST/GET/SESSION in your database.

Comment: Thank you GnarfDwarf, can you please tell me what is the best way or alternative to store the raw data from POST& SESSION?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and time. Will make sure to implement